# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed --> in while(any( loop

Tags: r, while-loop, any

I'm trying to number different rain-events! each new event starts (gets a new number), if there was no rainfall for a certain period of time (time.steps.event.end). But somehow R gives me an Error-message. Funny is, that the same code works, with a shorter list of measurements (in the same format). To your information: R always gives me the Error at i=1577739 out of 1577809 measurements.

This is (the faulty part of) my code:

```
 i=1
 rain.index=0
 finedata=rain.series.matrix[,3]

 while(i<(length(finedata)-time.steps.event.end+1)) { 
   if (finedata[i]==0)
     i=i+1 else {

  rain.index=rain.index+1

  rain.series.matrix[(i-max(durations)/20):i,2]=rain.index


  while(any(finedata[(i+1):(i+time.steps.event.end)]>0)) 
  {
    i=i+1
    rain.series.matrix[i,2]=rain.index

  }
  rain.series.matrix[(i+1):(i+time.steps.event.end),2]=rain.index
  i=i+1
}
}
```

The following Error is showing:

```
Error in while (any(finedata[(i + 1):(i + time.steps.event.end)] > 0,  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Although I love the enthusiasm for numbering rain events, it's hard to give a specific answer because you have not provided enough data/code.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you that you are trying to compare two things, but one of them is missing.

Here is a more succinct, reproducible example

```
x <- 1:2
x[3:4]
#[1] NA NA
while(any(x[3:4] > 0)) print(TRUE)
#Error in while (any(x[3:4] > 0)) print(TRUE) : 
#  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Maybe you could specifically check for NAs like this

```
while(!any(is.na(x[3:4])) && any(x[3:4] > 0)) print(TRUE)
```